OCN- has FOUR resonance structures?
My textbook gave the three most commonly seen resonance structures for OCN-:

But then it said calculations show that the contributions are 61%, 30%, and 4% for the structures from left to right. Those three numbers only add up to 95%. My professor said that the remaining 5% comes from a CN Quadruple bond and a zero-order bond with oxygen. How does that work?

This is a subtle result of molecular orbital theory. There are actually six orbitals oriented along the bond axis, and careful electron counting reveals that four of them are occupied. The fourth, highest occupied, sigma orbital is formally nonbonding on nitrogen, but careful MO calculation reveals that it is slightly bonding between carbon and nitrogen but antibonding between carbon and oxygen. Hence the fourth carbon-nitrogen bond.
Bear in mind, however, that this is only a minor contribution. The overall carbon-nitrogen interaction will look energetically like it's between a double bond and a triple bond.
